# asynchronous functions not executing sequentially as it should be

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

My code is behaving in a weird way. Here is a snippet and its output:

```
  let files = //files is an array

  Promise.each(files, file => {
    return epub.file(file.name).async('string').then(content => {
        let mmls = //mmls is an array

        Promise.each(mmls, mml => {
          return mj.typeset({math: mml, format: 'MathML', svg: true}).then(mjdata => {
            // do something
          })
        }).then(() => {
          console.log(0)
        })
    })
  }).then(() => {
    console.log(1)
  })
```

It would log in the console:

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
0  // one '0' after '1'
```

I found it weird how did one last '0' is logged if the '1' is already logged?

FYI: I'm using bluebird.

Comment: You probably need to `return Promise.each(...)` from within the inner callback, it can't chain it probably otherwise.

Comment: @sp00m wow that solved it. Do you mind explaining how did it fix by returning the `Promise.each(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say both promises take 1 second to execute, if you don't chain your promises correctly:

```
somePromise.then(() => {
    // 1.
    someOtherPromise.then(() => {
        // 3.
        console.log("inner");
    });
}).then(() => {
    // 2.
    console.log("outer");
});
```

First, `1.` will occur after t+1s. It then triggers `someOtherPromise`, but doesn't wait for it, so `1.` finishes "synchronously", leading to `2.` being executed (at t+1s+Ɛns). At t+2s, `3.` is executed. If you do wait for the other promise though:

```
somePromise.then(() => {
    // 1.
    return someOtherPromise.then(() => {
        // 2.
        console.log("inner");
    });
}).then(() => {
    // 3.
    console.log("outer");
});
```

First, `1.` will occur after t+1s. It then triggers `someOtherPromise`, but it does wait for it: `3.` will be called only once the returned promise is resolved. So `2.` occurs at t+2s, then `3.` occurs at t+2s+Ɛns.

Side note: in the functional world, you usually have `.map` and `.flatMap`, but JS Promise's `.then` mixes both depending on what the callback returned thanks to dynamic typing.